# Comparing daily value in each year in DataFrame to same day-number's value in another specific year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, time-series

I have a daily time series of closing prices of a financial instrument going back to 1990.

I am trying to compare the daily percentage change for each trading day of the previous years to it's respective trading day in 2019. I have 41 trading days of data for 2019 at this time.

I get so far as filtering down and creating a new DataFrame with only the first 41 dates, closing prices, daily percentage changes, and the "trading day of year" ("tdoy") classifier for each day in the set, but am not having luck from there.

I've found other Stack Overflow questions that help people compare `datetime` days, weeks, years, etc. but I am not able to recreate this because of the arbitrary value each "tdoy" represents.

I won't bother creating a sample DataFrame because of the number of rows so I've linked the CSV I've come up with to this point: [Sample CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GlqQdR0p43sXU4hsz1cryPaDnxrZsoWL/view?usp=sharing).

I think the easiest approach would just be to create a new column that returns what the 2019 percentage change is for each corresponding "tdoy" (Trading Day of Year) using `df.loc`, and if I could figure this much out I could then create yet another column to do the simple difference between that year/day's percentage change to 2019's respective value. Below is what I try to use (and I've tried other variations) to no avail.
`df['2019'] = df['perc'].loc[((df.year == 2019) & (df.tdoy == df.tdoy))]`

I've tried to search Stack and Google in probably 20 different variations of my problem and can't seem to find an answer that fits my issue of arbitrary "Trading Day of Year" classification.

I'm sure the answer is right in front of my face somewhere but I am still new to data wrangling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to import the csv properly. I'm not sure if you made the adjustment, but your data's date column is a string object.

```
# import the csv and assign to df. parse dates to datetime
df = pd.read_csv('TimeSeriesEx.csv', parse_dates=['Dates'])

# filter the dataframe so that you only have 2019 and 2018 data
df=df[df['year'] >= 2018]
df.tail()

    Unnamed: 0  Dates       last    perc        year    tdoy
1225    7601    2019-02-20  29.96   0.007397    2019    37
1226    7602    2019-02-21  30.49   0.017690    2019    38
1227    7603    2019-02-22  30.51   0.000656    2019    39
1228    7604    2019-02-25  30.36   -0.004916   2019    40
1229    7605    2019-02-26  30.03   -0.010870   2019    41
```

Put the tdoy and year into a multiindex.

```
# create a multiindex
df.set_index(['tdoy','year'], inplace=True)

df.tail()

                    Dates       last    perc
tdoy    year                
37  2019    7601    2019-02-20  29.96   0.007397
38  2019    7602    2019-02-21  30.49   0.017690
39  2019    7603    2019-02-22  30.51   0.000656
40  2019    7604    2019-02-25  30.36   -0.004916
41  2019    7605    2019-02-26  30.03   -0.010870
```

Make pivot table

```
# make a pivot table and assign it to a variable
df1 = df.pivot_table(values='last', index='tdoy', columns='year')

df1.head()

year 2018   2019
tdoy        
1   33.08   27.55
2   33.38   27.90
3   33.76   28.18
4   33.74   28.41
5   33.65   28.26
```

Create calculated column

```
# create the new column
df1['pct_change'] = (df1[2019]-df1[2018])/df1[2018]

df1

year 2018   2019    pct_change
tdoy            
1   33.08   27.55   -0.167170
2   33.38   27.90   -0.164170
3   33.76   28.18   -0.165284
4   33.74   28.41   -0.157973
5   33.65   28.26   -0.160178
6   33.43   28.18   -0.157045
7   33.55   28.32   -0.155887
8   33.29   27.94   -0.160709
9   32.97   28.17   -0.145587
10  32.93   28.11   -0.146371
11  32.93   28.24   -0.142423
12  32.79   28.23   -0.139067
13  32.51   28.77   -0.115042
14  32.23   29.01   -0.099907
15  32.28   29.01   -0.101301
16  32.16   29.06   -0.096393
17  32.52   29.38   -0.096556
18  32.68   29.51   -0.097001
19  32.50   30.03   -0.076000
20  32.79   30.30   -0.075938
21  32.87   30.11   -0.083967
22  33.08   30.42   -0.080411
23  33.07   30.17   -0.087693
24  32.90   29.89   -0.091489
25  32.51   30.13   -0.073208
26  32.50   30.38   -0.065231
27  33.16   30.90   -0.068154
28  32.56   30.81   -0.053747
29  32.21   30.87   -0.041602
30  31.96   30.24   -0.053817
31  31.85   30.33   -0.047724
32  31.57   29.99   -0.050048
33  31.80   29.89   -0.060063
34  31.70   29.95   -0.055205
35  31.54   29.95   -0.050412
36  31.54   29.74   -0.057070
37  31.86   29.96   -0.059636
38  32.07   30.49   -0.049267
39  32.04   30.51   -0.047753
40  32.36   30.36   -0.061805
41  32.62   30.03   -0.079399
```

Altogether without comments and data, the codes looks like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('TimeSeriesEx.csv', parse_dates=['Dates'])
df=df[df['year'] >= 2018]
df.set_index(['tdoy','year'], inplace=True)
df1 = df.pivot_table(values='last', index='tdoy', columns='year')
df1['pct_change'] = (df1[2019]-df1[2018])/df1[2018]
```

[EDIT] poster requesting for all dates compared to 2019.

```
df = pd.read_csv('TimeSeriesEx.csv', parse_dates=['Dates'])
df.set_index(['tdoy','year'], inplace=True)
```

Ignore year filter above, create pivot table

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(values='last', index='tdoy', columns='year')
```

Create a loop going through the years/columns and create a new field for each year comparing to 2019.

```
for y in df1.columns:    
    df1[str(y) + '_pct_change'] = (df1[2019]-df1[y])/df1[y]
```

To view some data...

```
df1.loc[1:4, "1990_pct_change":"1994_pct_change"]

year    1990_pct_change 1991_pct_change 1992_pct_change 1993_pct_change 1994_pct_change
tdoy                    
1       0.494845        0.328351        0.489189        0.345872    -0.069257
2       0.496781        0.364971        0.516304        0.361640    -0.045828
3       0.523243        0.382050        0.527371        0.369956    -0.035262
4       0.524960        0.400888        0.531536        0.367838    -0.034659
```

Final code for all years:

```
df = pd.read_csv('TimeSeriesEx.csv', parse_dates=['Dates'])
df.set_index(['tdoy','year'], inplace=True)
df1 = df.pivot_table(values='last', index='tdoy', columns='year')
for y in df1.columns:    
    df1[str(y) + '_pct_change'] = (df1[2019]-df1[y])/df1[y]

df1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe the end result I was looking for was not the most efficient way to accomplish my ultimate goal of finding the most similar year(s) based on the trend of daily percentage change values. Without having some sort of loop, is there a way to alter what you did above to make this calculation not just for 2018 vs. 2019 but for each year in the range of 1990-2018 versus 2019?

Comment: Which trend are you looking for exactly?

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. It is an approach I didn't previously consider. I also worked out creating a new `df` of just the 2019 `tdoy` and `perc` values and zipping them to a `dict`, then creating a new column on the original dataframe mapping the `tdoy` as the key to its value pair in the `dict`. Then create another column to find the difference between that year's value and the 2019 value and square it. I then would need to do some groupby year function find the lowest value(s) to come up with most similar years. I will perhaps create my own answer as an alternative but pivot is helpful.

Comment: With regards to what trend I am looking for, I ultimately plan to do some sort of wavelet transformation (little out of my league at the moment) to transform the previous years to have a similar scale to the year I am comparing against (2019). For now, I was just looking to find which year's percentage change difference by day versus 2019 is lowest and I can then say, per that calculation, that the percentage change has trended most similar in 1999, for example, vs 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with my own answer more along the lines of what I was trying to originally accomplish. DataFrame I'll work with for the example. `df`:

`Dates         last       perc     year   tdoy
0   2016-01-04  29.93   -0.020295   2016    2
1   2016-01-05  29.63   -0.010023   2016    3
2   2016-01-06  29.59   -0.001350   2016    4
3   2016-01-07  29.44   -0.005069   2016    5
4   2017-01-03  34.57   0.004358    2017    2
5   2017-01-04  34.98   0.011860    2017    3
6   2017-01-05  35.00   0.000572    2017    4
7   2017-01-06  34.77   -0.006571   2017    5
8   2018-01-02  33.38   0.009069    2018    2
9   2018-01-03  33.76   0.011384    2018    3
10  2018-01-04  33.74   -0.000592   2018    4
11  2018-01-05  33.65   -0.002667   2018    5
12  2019-01-02  27.90   0.012704    2019    2
13  2019-01-03  28.18   0.010036    2019    3
14  2019-01-04  28.41   0.008162    2019    4
15  2019-01-07  28.26   -0.005280   2019    5`

I created a DataFrame with only the 2019 values for `tdoy` and `perc`

`df19 = df[['tdoy','perc']].loc[df['year'] == 2019]`

and then zipped a dictionary for those values
`perc19 = dict(zip(df19.tdoy,df19.perc))`

to end up with

`perc19=
{2: 0.012704174228675058,
 3: 0.010035842293906852,
 4: 0.008161816891412365,
 5: -0.005279831045406497}`

Then map these keys with the `tdoy` column in the original DataFrame to create a column titled `2019` that has the corresponding 2019 percentage change value for that trading day

`df['2019'] = df['tdoy'].map(perc19)`

and then create a `vs2019` column where I find the difference of `2019` vs. `perc` and square it yielding

`Dates          last      perc       year   tdoy      2019       vs2019
0   2016-01-04  29.93   -0.020295   2016    2   0.012704    6.746876
1   2016-01-05  29.63   -0.010023   2016    3   0.010036    3.995038
2   2016-01-06  29.59   -0.001350   2016    4   0.008162    1.358162
3   2016-01-07  29.44   -0.005069   2016    5   -0.005280   0.001590
4   2017-01-03  34.57   0.004358    2017    2   0.012704    0.431608
5   2017-01-04  34.98   0.011860    2017    3   0.010036    0.033038
6   2017-01-05  35.00   0.000572    2017    4   0.008162    0.864802
7   2017-01-06  34.77   -0.006571   2017    5   -0.005280   0.059843
8   2018-01-02  33.38   0.009069    2018    2   0.012704    0.081880
9   2018-01-03  33.76   0.011384    2018    3   0.010036    0.018047
10  2018-01-04  33.74   -0.000592   2018    4   0.008162    1.150436`

From here I can groupby in various ways and further calculate to find most similar trending percentage changes vs. the year I am comparing against (2019).